# Angular 5 Http Errors not returning from web service call

Tags: angular, http, error-handling

I am making a web service call in Angular 5, using the HttpClientModule, and it works for all 200 statuses response.  But, if there is any 400 statuses it just waits and waits and waits and eventually get a 503 status.

For example, if I call this function with correct username/password, it works, I get 200 status back, and the User object.  But, if I pass in incorrect username/password, I dont get the 400 error, I get a 503 error after about a minute.

The server side log shows that the webservice is returning a 400 status to my request, but nothing comes back.

Here is my web service call code:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  const url = this.getUrl('/v1/users/login');
  const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'transactionId': uuid.v4()})
  };
  const body = { username, password };

  return new Observable<boolean>( observer => {
    this.http.post<User>(url, body, headers).subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        console.log('login: Success: ', user);
        observer.next(true);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('login: Error: ', err);
        observer.next(false);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Here is the [Chrome Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HzS1.png) log:

Comment: What do you see in the network panel? Ultimately angular hands off a request to the browser and then it's between the browser and the server until the response comes back.

Comment: Posted image of the Chrome Network log

Comment: Is my code correct to handle error responses?

Comment: I'm still a noob with anything beyond angular 1.x myself but it looks reasonable off hand, other thing is based on your image of the network request it's something after your web server has said 400 bad credentials or whatever and the response being sent to the browser (since it sees a 503) you can right click the request in the network panel and copy as curl request then paste that in a unix terminal with curl installed (or cygwin) and see the request outside of the browser but will likely get the same 503 response.  Basically I'm thinking something on heroku config maybe?

Comment: Here is a wrinkle.  It works in postman and returns the 400 error no problem.

Comment: The plot thickens... :) sorry not sure what else to check here really maybe use Charles web debugging proxy or wireshark to get a little deeper on the network request inspection but can't say I've seen this one... it does seem to be between chrome and the server, only thing angular really does here is setup the XHR object (some default request headers etc.).  On the 503 response coming back and showing in the network panel that's between the server and browser.  If you can save the request/response where it works vs fails can diff and see what surfaces.

Comment: I just downloaded Charles Web Debugging proxy, and I feel like I am seeing something odd.

When I perform my request, it looks like I have two requests, one that is 204 status with a type of OPTIONS

And one with a 503 status with a type of POST.    Did this happen because of the 503.

When I run this in postman, I get one single POST with a returned status of 400.

Comment: Ah okay this does make sense check out CORS you must be requesting from a client served from a different domain/port from the server, surprised I didn't think of it earlier.  Your server needs to respond with the appropriate response headers to allow the client to communicate with it.

Comment: actually on second thought not sure why it would be ok for the 200 responses... strange still... but something

Comment: Yes, the server is on a different machine,and we have it configured with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: For some reason, POSTMAN does not send the pre-flight check at all, and it works.

Comment: POSTMan does act more like curl where it basically isn't tied to a domain https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/170 guess since it's an extension it acts more like a domain-less request.  I'd look for any details in the 503 or anything else you can do on the heroku side to debug what gets sent back

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the server had a bug in it.  It was getting an error in the log regarding "media type".  Once that was resolved, the server is now sending back correct error responses and my code is handing them.

Comment: Glad you figured it out and was in fact something server side.  In most cases angular isn't really to blame or suspect in situations like this because the httpservice is basically a wrapper around the xhr object native to browsers (also widely used and tested)